# How can I change cbuttoncolumn label dynamically in yii cgridview

Tags: php, yii, cgridview, cbuttoncolumn

I am trying to change cbuttoncolumn label dyanamically. But somehow it does not work. My code is

```
array(
      'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
      'template'=>'{publish}',
      'buttons'=>array(
          'publish'=>array(
             //'type'=>'raw',
             'label'=>'$data->content_type == 1 ? "View & Publish" : "Publish"',
             'icon'=>'ok',
             'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/admin/contentToPublish/publish")',
           ),
       ),
),
```

How can i do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new column with custom links, something like this:

In your **model** :

```
public function getMyValue(){
    $linkOne = CHtml::link("$this->labelOne", Yii::app()->createUrl("model/action",array("id"=>$this->id)));
    $linkTwo = CHtml::link("$this->labelTwo", Yii::app()->createUrl("model/action",array("id"=>$this->id)));
    return $linkOne.' '.$linkTwo;
}
```

And in your **CGridView** :

```
'columns'=>array(
        'labelOne',
        'labelTwo',
        array(
            'type' => 'raw',
            'header' => 'Manage',
            'value' => '$data->getMyValue()',
            ),

    ),
```

Or, you can use the `visible` attribute in `CButtonColumn`:

```
array(
      'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
      'template'=>'{publish}{viewPublish}',
      'buttons'=>array(
          'publish'=>array(
             //'type'=>'raw',
             'label'=>'Publish',
             'visible' => '$data->content_type != "1"',
             'icon'=>'ok',
             'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/admin/contentToPublish/publish")',
           ),
          'viewPublish'=>array(
             //'type'=>'raw',
             'label'=>'View & Publish',
             'visible' => '$data->content_type == "1"',
             'icon'=>'ok',
             'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/admin/contentToPublish/publish")',
           ),
       ),
),
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: That does not work man. Your visible codition does not work I think.